# Collision between two balls so they can bounce off of each other

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I just want a simple collision detection so these balls bounce off of each other and if you can also hit me up with a better way of coding these types of animations , ill be happy. Ive heard there is a better way for doing that with object oriented Javascript , but it seems complicated for me since im still a beginner. Please try to explain the code you suggest me since im still learning .

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canv");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var x = canvas.width/2;
var x2 = canvas.width/2;
var y = canvas.height-20;
var y2 = 20;
var ballRadius = 20;
var ballRadius2 = 20;
var dx = 2;
var dy = -2;
var dx2 = 2;
var dy2 = 2;
function drawBall(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y,ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}
function drawBall2(){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x2, y2,ballRadius2, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}
function draw(){
    drawBall();
    drawBall2();
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
    x2 += dx2;
    y2 += dy2
    if (x && x2 > canvas.width - ballRadius || x && x2 < ballRadius){
    dx = -dx;
    dx2 = -dx2;
    }
    if (y && y2 > canvas.height - ballRadius || y && y2 < 0){
    dy = -dy;
    dy2 = -dy2;
    }

 }
setInterval(draw, 10);
```

if you guys can help me simplifying this code too ill be thankful.

Comment: You can find the maths for "snooker ball" collision here on Hugo Elias' (sadly now defunct, hence the archive.org URL) site: https://web.archive.org/web/20090627214007/http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_snokr.htm

Comment: You should rephrase the question to tell us what the *problem* is with your code, and where exactly you are stuck. Just asking for code that performs collision detection is not how this site works. If however your code works as intended, and you want to have it reviewed, then go to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Do note that Code Review could review your code if it works as intended, but it's not the place to ask for alternative implementations (although those are at times part of the reviews provided).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question! I wanted to say goodjob on diving into javascript and HTML5. Both of these are fantastic tools that will surely help you put together some awesome projects.

Now to the question. You are asking how to do a simple collision test between the two balls. I will explain this shortly, but before I do, I wanted to give you a reference on [Javascript object oriented programming](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS).

The collision test between the two balls is very similar to the collision test with the walls. The main difference is that you can't consider only the `x` or the `y` value alone, you must consider them both simultaneously.

With this in mind, the balls need to 'bounce' if the distance between them with respect to `x` and `y` is equal to or less than their combined radius.

[image: x = radius1 + radius2]

Now all that is left is to convert that logical statement into a javascript logical statement. I have provided one potential solution, and urge you to make a better one if you are able to.

```
//test for 'hits' with eachother
if((Math.abs(ballOne.x - ballTwo.x) < (ballOne.radius + ballTwo.radius)) && (Math.abs(ballOne.y - ballTwo.y) < (ballOne.radius + ballTwo.radius)))
{
    //reverse ball one
    ballOne.dx = -ballOne.dx;
    ballOne.dy = -ballOne.dy;

    //reverse ball two
    ballTwo.dx = -ballTwo.dx;
    ballTwo.dy = -ballTwo.dy;
}
```

I have also provided what I would consider a 'simpler' and certainly easier solution to your current project. I suggest reading through this and utilizing the documents at the link above to better understand Javascript OOP.

**Goodluck, and Happy coding!**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <canvas id="canv" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    
     <script>
     //define canvas object
     var canvas = document.getElementById("canv");
     var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    
     //define ball objects
     var ballOne;
     var ballTwo;
    
     //javascript 'constructor function' for ball
     function Ball(x, y, dx, dy, radius, color){
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.dx = dx;
      this.dy = dy;
      this.radius = radius;
      this.color = color;
     }
    
     function wallCollisionDetection(balls){
      
      //for loop to 'go through' the array of balls
      var i;
      for(i = 0; i < balls.length; i++){
       //collision test between a ball and a wall
        //x-direction tests
        if((balls[i].x + balls[i].radius >= canvas.width) || (balls[i].x - balls[i].radius <= 0) ){ balls[i].dx = -balls[i].dx; }
    
        //y-direction tests
        if((balls[i].y + balls[i].radius >= canvas.height) || (balls[i].y - balls[i].radius <= 0) ){ balls[i].dy = -balls[i].dy; }
      } 
     }
    
     function updateBall(ball){
      ball.x += ball.dx;
      ball.y += ball.dy;
     }
     
     function drawBall(ball){
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
      ctx.fillStyle = ball.color;
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.closePath();
     }
     function draw(){
    
      //draw both ball objects
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      drawBall(ballOne);
      drawBall(ballTwo);
      
      //update the balls' x & y based on the balls' dx & dy
      updateBall(ballOne);
      updateBall(ballTwo);
      
      //test for 'hits' with the walls
      wallCollisionDetection([ballOne, ballTwo]);
      
      //test for 'hits' with eachother
      if((Math.abs(ballOne.x - ballTwo.x) < (ballOne.radius + ballTwo.radius)) && (Math.abs(ballOne.y - ballTwo.y) < (ballOne.radius + ballTwo.radius)))
      {
       //reverse ball one
       ballOne.dx = -ballOne.dx;
       ballOne.dy = -ballOne.dy;
    
       //reverse ball two
       ballTwo.dx = -ballTwo.dx;
       ballTwo.dy = -ballTwo.dy;
      }
      
     }
     function initializeBalls(){
      //set-up ball objects
      ballOne = new Ball(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height - 50, 2, -2, 15, "green");
      ballTwo = new Ball(canvas.width / 2, 40, 3, 2, 35, "blue");
     }
     initializeBalls();
     setInterval(draw, 10);
     </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: These collisions look unnatural. Looking at your code you seem to assume that when balls collide, their direction becomes opposite, but that is not how it works. Imagine balls that slide past eachother in opposite direction, only barely hitting eachother at their sides,... then certainly their path will not proceed in the opposite way.

Comment: I agree that the collisions aren't very good, he did ask for 'simple collision detection' which I did provide. The collision detection is fine how it is. He physics of the collision could be more complex and natural, but that is beyond the scope of the question asked by the OP.